# octopress-avatar: where is the avatar image file?

Tags: octopress

The path to the avatar is not described.
Where should be stored the avatar in order to use this plugin.

```
in source/images ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a url straight in the config file:

```
avatar_url: http://www.foo.com/avatar.jpg
```

so you might as well upload the image in your directory and use the full url for it in the config file.

```
avatar_url: http://www.foo.com/images/avatar.jpg
```